# Regex to test an expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this expression:

```
/width*$/.test(oldStyle)
```

And oldStyle has this inside of it:

```
width:90%;height:inherit;padding-left:20px;
```

The expression should return true as i have tested it in a online JavaScript regex expression tool.

Why is this returning false?

Can i use this expression the way i have coded?

Comment: the regex checks for `widt` followed by *any amount of `h` characters* and then the end of the line. So, it won't match anything but a line ending in `widt`, `width`, `widthh`, `widthhh` and so on.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't *end* with width, which is what you're enforcing via `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.` to match any character followed by the `*` to match 1 or more.

```js
const oldStyle = 'width:90%;height:inherit;padding-left:20px;';
const result = /width.*$/.test(oldStyle);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Result: " + result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```